# Adding Html Canvas inside a css grid layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have been trying to include a html canvas that I've created inside one of the css grid classes that I've declared in my code. The code executes when the button "Calculate"is pressed.

Once the button is pressed, the `<div>` section declared for the canvas stays unchanged, but another canvas is drawn outside the grid `<div>`, in the html body. However the canvas ids are the same for both canvases, since I've declared a canvas id.

I cannot seem to find the reason why it creates its own canvas even though I have given the correct canvas id.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Staging Area Simulation</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="public_html/jquery.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #canvas {
            border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }

        .grid-container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
            background-color: #2196F3;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .grid-item {
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
            border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
            padding: 20px;
            font-size: 30px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<!--<body onload="startGame()">-->

<body>
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div>
            <canvas id="canvas" width="480" height="480">

            </canvas>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h3>Enter Parameters</h3>
            <p id="sBubble">Safety bubble : 0.0 m</p>
            Sliding Window :<p id="window"></p>
            <form method="get" id="form">
                speed : <input type="integer" id="speed" name="speed" /> <br /><br />
                Vehicle Length : <input type="text" id="vLength" name="vLength" value="3.84m" disabled />
                <br /><br />
                Vehicle Width : <input type="text" id="vWidth" name="vWidth" value="1.74m" disabled />
                <br /><br />
                <button name="data" type="button" onclick="calculateBubble()">Calculate</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div style="text-align:center;width:480px;">
            <h3>
                Red Controllers </h3>
                    <button onmousedown="redmoveup()" onmouseup="clearmove()">UP</button><br><br>
                    <button onmousedown="redmoveleft()" onmouseup="clearmove()">LEFT</button>
                    <button onmousedown="redmoveright()" onmouseup="clearmove()">RIGHT</button><br><br>
                    <button onmousedown="redmovedown()" onmouseup="clearmove()">DOWN</button>
        </div>

        <div style="text-align:center;width:480px;">
            <h3> Blue Controllers</h3>
            <button onmousedown="bluemoveup()" onmouseup="clearmove()">UP</button><br><br>
            <button onmousedown="bluemoveleft()" onmouseup="clearmove()">LEFT</button>
            <button onmousedown="bluemoveright()" onmouseup="clearmove()">RIGHT</button><br><br>
            <button onmousedown="bluemovedown()" onmouseup="clearmove()">DOWN</button>
        </div>

    </div>

<script>

//  var speed = urlParam('speed');
//    if (speed == null)
//        speed = 40
//    $('#speed').val(speed);
//  calculateBubble(parseInt(speed));

    var redSBLatter;
    var redSBFormer;

    var redSBWindowFormer;
    var redSBWindowLatter;

    var blueSB;

    var blueSWindow;

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.getElementById("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
    },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}

    function startGame(bubbleLength, windowLength) {
        redSBWindowFormer = new slidingWindow(60, windowLength * 2, "black", 5, 120);
        redSBWindowLatter = new slidingWindow(60, 40, "black", 5, 80);
        redSBFormer = new component(30, bubbleLength, "red", 20, 120);
        redSBLatter = new component(30, 30, "red", 20, 90);

        blueSWindow = new slidingWindow(60, 70, "black", 120, 10);
        blueSB = new component(20, 40, "blue", 140, 20);
        myGameArea.start();
    }

    function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.speedX = 0;
        this.speedY = 0;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.update = function () {
            ctx = myGameArea.context;
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
        this.newPos = function () {
            this.x += this.speedX;
            this.y += this.speedY;
        }
    }

    function slidingWindow(width, height, color, x, y) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.speedX = 0;
        this.speedY = 0;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.update = function () {
            ctx = myGameArea.context;
            ctx.beginPath();
            //ctx.globalAlpha = 0.2;
            ctx.lineWidth = "3";
            ctx.strokeStyle = color;
            ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        this.newPos = function () {
            this.x += this.speedX;
            this.y += this.speedY;
        }
    }

    function updateGameArea() {
        myGameArea.clear();
        redSBLatter.newPos();
        redSBLatter.update();
        redSBFormer.newPos();
        redSBFormer.update();
        redSBWindowLatter.newPos();
        redSBWindowLatter.update();
        redSBWindowFormer.newPos();
        redSBWindowFormer.update();
        blueSB.newPos();
        blueSB.update();
        blueSWindow.newPos();
        blueSWindow.update();
    }

    function redmoveup() {
        redSBLatter.speedY = -1;
        redSBFormer.speedY = -1;
        redSBWindowLatter.speedY = -1;
        redSBWindowFormer.speedY = -1;

    }

    function bluemoveup() {
        blueSB.speedY = -1;
        blueSWindow.speedY = -1;
    }

    function redmovedown() {
        redSBLatter.speedY = 1;
        redSBFormer.speedY = 1;
        redSBWindowLatter.speedY = 1;
        redSBWindowFormer.speedY = 1;
    }

    function bluemovedown() {
        blueSB.speedY = 1;
        blueSWindow.speedY = 1;
    }

    function redmoveleft() {
        redSBLatter.speedX = -1;
        redSBFormer.speedX = -1;
        redSBWindowLatter.speedX = -1;
        redSBWindowFormer.speedX = -1;
    }

    function bluemoveleft() {
        blueSB.speedX = -1;
        blueSWindow.speedX = -1;
    }

    function redmoveright() {
        redSBLatter.speedX = 1;
        redSBFormer.speedX = 1;
        redSBWindowLatter.speedX = 1;
        redSBWindowFormer.speedX = 1;
    }

    function bluemoveright() {
        blueSB.speedX = 1;
        blueSWindow.speedX = 1;
    }

    function clearmove() {
        redSBLatter.speedX = 0;
        redSBLatter.speedY = 0;
        redSBFormer.speedX = 0;
        redSBFormer.speedY = 0;
        redSBWindowLatter.speedX = 0;
        redSBWindowLatter.speedY = 0;
        redSBWindowFormer.speedX = 0;
        redSBWindowFormer.speedY = 0;
        blueSB.speedX = 0;
        blueSB.speedY = 0;
        blueSWindow.speedX = 0;
        blueSWindow.speedY = 0;
    }

/**    function calculateBubble() {
        var kmh = document.getElementById("speed").value;
        if (kmh <= 0) {
            var bubble = 5.84;
            var window = bubble * 5;
            document.getElementById("bubble").innerHTML = bubble;
            document.getElementById("window").innerHTML = window;
            return startGame(20, 20);
        }
        else {
            //var v = getMph(kmh);
            var v = kmh / 1.6093;
            var feet = 2.2 * v + ((v * v) / 20);
            var bubblemeters = feet / 3.28;
            var bubble = parseFloat(bubblemeters.toFixed(2));

            document.getElementById("bubble").innerHTML = bubble;

            calculateWindow(bubble);

            return bubblemeters;
        }
    }**/

    function calculateBubble() {
        var kmh = document.getElementById("speed").value;
        var v = kmh / 1.6093;
        var feet = 2.2 * v + ((v * v) / 20)
        var meters = feet / 3.28;
        $('#sBubble').empty();
        $('#sBubble').append("Safety bubble : " + meters.toFixed(2) + " m");
        calculateWindow(meters);
    }

    function calculateWindow(bubble) {

        var windowMeters = bubble + 5;
        var window = parseFloat(windowMeters.toFixed());

        document.getElementById("window").innerHTML = window;
        startGame(bubble, window);

    }

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try replaing

```
canvas : document.createElement("canvas")
```

with

```
canvas : document.getElementById("mycanvas")
```

You can probably also remove the line

```
myGameArea.canvas.id = "myCanvas";
```

Comment: I tried this. The canvas that I made no longer appears outside the grid. But it does not appear at all. :( What do you think might be the reason?

Comment: I adjusted a few lines of code and it appears again, but still outside the grid.